# Data Equalizer not working with Foundation 6 Modal (Reveal)

Tags: javascript, zurb-foundation

I have a modal in Foundation 6 and I would like to be able to use the Data Equalizer with it. Everything I have found seems to be pointing to Foundation 5.

I found this page, [foundation plugin page](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/javascript.html#adding-content-to-plugins) and I think this is what I need, but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
$(document).on('closeme.zf.reveal', '#productModal', function () {

Foundation.reInit('equalizer');
console.log("modal fired");

});
```

Screen shot of modal.
[image]

Comment: What are you expecting and what are the results?

Comment: I would expect each column to be the same size in height. But since the modal has a display of none when the page loads and the display property is changed when the user clicks to see the modal to a display of block. It seems the equalizer is not being triggered when the display property is changed.  What I am seeing is each column stacked on top of each other.

Comment: Can you please post a screenshot of what the modal looks like at the moment?

Comment: Can I also please see the html structure of the modal?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use this javascript to solve my issue.

I added this to the function that opened up my modal

Foundation.reInit('equalizer');

It forces the Foundation framework to initialize itself, and since this is called after the modal goes from a display of none to a display of block, it works.